# Amplitude lines + geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I would like to add a some aditional lines to this plot. I must to show the distance for max and min data, from horizontal and vertical, like the example below.
Is like to add boxplots without the boxes

I have tried follow this example, but without success. [Avoid plot overlay using geom_point in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740803/avoid-plot-overlay-using-geom-point-in-ggplot2)

I did this on photoshop. But, how can i add on R?

**Original plot**

```
plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(gear))) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle("Cars")

plot
```

[image: simple cars plot]

**Modded version**

[image]

Comment: These may get you started: [How to draw lines outside of plot area in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2), [ggplot2 - annotate outside of plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot)

Comment: Here's an answer with a variety of ways to do marginal histograms and rug plots: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8545035/5325862 None of them are lines out of the box like you're looking for, but I'm thinking about ways to adapt those solutions to do a line instead of a histogram

Comment: Thank you Henrik.  @camille this will be very usefull. I just added a new column with zeros on my db and now i'm doing scatter plots based on factors. this method will work fine i think.

Comment: You might also look at the internals of `ggExtra::ggMarginal`. It lets you choose from density, histogram, boxplot, or violin for the summaries, and you can do them by group; you might be able to replicate that code but do maybe a `geom_segment` instead of the other summaries used there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this result. (on original plot)

I built 3 plots + a empty one, like suggested here: [Scatterplot with marginal histograms in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2)

to the horizontal and vertical plots i used:

```
horizontal <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, gear, colour = factor(gear)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,-0.4,0.7), "cm")) +
    xlab("") + ylab("")

horizontal <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, colour = factor(gear)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,-0.4,0.7), "cm")) +
    xlab("") + ylab("")
```

The best fit is achieved managing the margins in each plot.

Then, the empty plot

```
empty <- ggplot()+geom_point(aes(1,1), colour="white")+
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
          panel.background=element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),           
          axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

so, join everything

```
grid.arrange(horizontal, empty, plot, vertical, ncol=2, nrow=2, 
             widths=c(1, 0.05), heights=c(0.5, 4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got intensely curious about this, but found that my go-to, `cowplot`, wouldn't quite space the plots properly. The package writer himself [suggested using `patchwork`](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/31) instead for more complex spacing and alignment. With `cowplot`, I'd made a dummy `ggplot` to hold the top right as a blank space, but couldn't get the heights right. `patchwork` instead has a `plot_spacing` function to do this.

The first task was to make a summary data frame for drawing the lines. I added a row number so there was a way to stack the lines vertically for the top margin, and horizontally for the right margin. (I suppose a dummy value and `position_dodge` may have worked also.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

summaries <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(minwt = min(wt), maxwt = max(wt), minmpg = min(mpg), maxmpg = max(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())

summaries
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>    gear minwt maxwt minmpg maxmpg   row
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1     3  2.46  5.42   10.4   21.5     1
#> 2     4  1.62  3.44   17.8   33.9     2
#> 3     5  1.51  3.57   15     30.4     3
```

I made the top and right plots, using the same `ggplot` base, and gave them `theme_void` so there would be nothing shown except the segments themselves. I'd suggest going through this with a different theme so you can see how the plots come together.

```r
summary_base <- ggplot(summaries, aes(color = factor(gear)))

top <- summary_base +
  geom_segment(aes(x = minwt, xend = maxwt, y = row, yend = row), show.legend = F) +
  theme_void()

right <- summary_base +
  geom_segment(aes(x = row, xend = row, y = minmpg, yend = maxmpg), show.legend = F) +
  theme_void()
```

Then the main plot:

```r
points <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Then `patchwork` allows you to just add the plots together. They go left to right, top to bottom, so to get the top right blank space, I used `plot_spacer`. Then `plot_layout` sets up the grid. You can adjust the relative heights and widths how you want—probably make them more narrow. This was my first time using `patchwork`, but it was very straightforward.

```r
top + plot_spacer() + points + right + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, widths = c(1, 0.2), heights = c(0.2, 1))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That's a great option too. Seems to be easier